# IBM CPLEX Ilog Error : "Excel size of range is not the size of the array"

Tags: arrays, size, cplex, ilog

I am connecting to excel for solving a problem. I had used the same .mod file to solve a problem with 27 rows of excel data. Now I am trying with an excel of 366 rows of data. I get an error  "Excel size of range is not the size of the array" for one of the data (values) where as the other data like Blocks are ok. I do not see a reason for this. Can anyone please tell me what may be causing this. The dat file is below :

```html
SheetConnection sheet("Pit113_Reserves_by_block.xlsx");

BlocksType from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!A2:D367");
Blocks from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!A2:A367");
TimePeriods from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!O2:O6");

value from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!H2:H367");
oreTons from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!F2:F367");
wasteTons from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!G2:G367");

resourceMaxCap from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!P2:P6");
processMinCap from SheetRead(sheet,"Data!Q2:Q6");

schedule to SheetWrite(sheet,"Data!I2:M367");
```

The mod file declaration part is below :

```html
    {int} TimePeriods =...;

{int} Blocks =...;



float value[Blocks] = ...;
float oreTons[Blocks] = ...;
float wasteTons[Blocks] = ...;
float resourceMaxCap[TimePeriods] =...;
float processMinCap[TimePeriods] =...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I figured out the issue. The Blocks value that I was using was not a continuous serial number. I had used some logic to identify a block by a discontinuous number based on its location. I changed it into a continuous number and it works now. Thank you for looking into this.